# Red5 Audio Recording

Tags: mp3, red5, audio-recording, xuggle

I want to record audio stream as mp3 file on server. I know flash media server can do this but I can not afford it.Red5 officially does not allow this. I have done research and found that we can record audio in flv then use ffmpeg to convert this to mp3. Is there any plugin available for red5 that can directly record audio as mp3 without doing conversion process. Can xuggler for Red5 do this.I am using Red5 for the first time so I am totally clueless.

Comment: just be aware that recording to MP3 (encoding actually) with or without FFMPEG requires MP3 licensing with small payment

Comment: OK.Which tool can i use for recording mp3 with red5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't record in mp3, you're only choice is recording the FLV and then use ffmpeg to convert it to mp3

Comment: Yeah. I used the same method.Thanks for the reply

Comment: Would you mind telling me how you managed to record the audio? I'm looking for tutorials myself, well more importantly than just recording but storing it.

Comment: I created a flash swf file with options to record and stop. When user clicked record, red5 started recording it. When user clicked stop button the flash player  started a php script that used php exec function to run ffmpeg command which converted recorded flv file which is stored in red5 folder for the application, to mp3.

Comment: would it be too much trouble to ask you to share the server code?

Comment: send me your email. Let me check if I have it I will send it to you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course Xuggler can handle the conversion to MP3 but there are ways to encode your stream into MP3 without using a server side process. Have a look at this project that does AS3 enabled MP3 encoding: http://code.google.com/p/as3lameencoder/

Original blog post: http://www.bytearray.org/?p=1142